# Event fired in dragdrop source when dragdrop is completed or cancelled

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, drag-and-drop

I know that there is usually a `DoDragDrop` method that starts a drag and drop operation. And that there are events (such as `DragEnter`, `DragOver`, `DragDrop`, `DragLeave`) that can be handled on the target side.

Are there any events on the source of the dragdrop that will tell me whether the dragdrop operation was completed, or possibly cancelled?

Comment: That's what DragOver does.  Just kidding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, DoDragDrop() has a return value.  It returns DragDropEffects.None if the drop was cancelled.

Comment: Another option is the `QueryContinueDrag` event, although in this case. I believe the return result would be most appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to a situation similar to **delete-on-paste** in Windows Explorer where a file is not deleted from the source folder until a Paste operation occurs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776904(VS.85).aspx#delete_on_paste

#### Easy Answer

If you are doing this within the same instance of the application, then this is referred to an **optimized move** where you can simply set a local flag (such as a boolean variable) to determine if it was successful.

**Update:**  Yes, you can also check the results of the DoDragDrop method to determine if the drop was successful.  Just make sure that your drop-handling code properly sets the Effect to None if there was an error completing the drop, or else your code with DoDragDrop will think that the drop was a success.  This method will even work between two instances of your application.

#### Hard Answer

If you are doing this between two instances of your application, and you need to transfer more information that just whether or not the drop was successful, then you need to implement the OLE version of `IDataObject` so that the application instance that is the drop target completes the drag and drop, it can call SetData on the source object to send result information.  This is complicated to do but is certainly possible.

For more information on doing this, see these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.idataobject.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/10/26/creating-something-from-nothing-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net.aspx